# Inserting date() into a database not working

Tags: php, insert, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I set $date as the current time, and when i insert it into the database it appears as a long decimal.

ex. 0.000059642147117296

Here's the code:

HTML

```
 <form id="comments" action="<?=site_url('headquarters/scopeSummary')?>" method="POST">
        <textarea name="comment" cols="70" rows="5"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="scopeId" value="<?=$id?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?=$user?>" />
        <br />
        Mark as important?<input type="checkbox" name="important" value="yes" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
 </form>
```

PHP

```
 if ($comment) {
    $date = date('n/d/Y', time());
    $comQuery = $this->db->query('INSERT INTO scope_comments VALUES(NULL, "'. $scopeId .'", "'. $comment .'", "'. $user .'", "", "", '. $date .', "'. $gravity .'")');
}
```

all the values being inserted are set. They are not the problem. Only the $date is messing up. Im using codeigniter and phpmyadmin.

Comment: SQL injection. That code begs for it.

Comment: what is the structure for the date field? `date`, `datetime`, `timestamp`?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neglected to quote the date value, so the system is computing something like 3/25/2012 (which is the `0.00005642147117296` you are seeing).

You are also specifying the date in the wrong format. It MUST be in the `Y-m-d` format.

Finally, chances are your database field is not defined as a date, so make sure to correct that table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the curren system time for insertion, it's by far easier to have

```
INSERT INTO ... (datefield) VALUES (NOW())
```

and have the database generate its own date value. This saves you the hassle of having to generate a string in PHP, quote/escape the string, then have MySQL parse that string back into its own format.